# Store unsubscribe vs. watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What is the proper way of listening to a getter in the store from a component?

Should a watch be used, or should I subscribe to it?

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
this.watcher_handle = this.$watch(() => {
    return this.$store.getters.someValue;
}, (new_value, old_value) => {
    // Do something cool
});
```

What is the difference in the two and advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) you want to do something like this.

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
      'doneTodosCount',
      'anotherGetter',
      // ...
    ])
  }
}
```

This would be the "proper way".

The vue documentation talks about the difference between [watchers and computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) and when [watchers should be used](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) basically for asynchronous or expensive operations **performed by the component**. I realize vuex methods are slightly different than computed properties, but the point is `watch` is meant to be used when no other better way exists.

The main benefit of subscribing to the vuex methods would be the same as why you would use vuex in the first place: abstraction of your store and enforcement of predictable data flow.

In your example the `//Do something cool` part would be abstracted into your vuex functions which makes your component simpler and also would make that particularly functionality reusable.

Why use vuex as your store and then not use its accessor methods? I see this as analogous to using vue-router but still doing URL manipulation in your component methods.

Comment: Yes, but what is the difference between doing this, using a watch, or subscribing?